# blocknotify ignores > /dev/null 2>&1 and fills up my debug log

Tags: bitcoin.conf, debugging

I have this code in my bitcoin.conf

`blocknotify=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v11.15.0/bin/node /home/BTC/block.js %s > /dev/null 2>&1`

I see the error

`runCommand error: system(/root/.nvm/versions/node/v11.15.0/bin/node /home/BTC/block.js ea31b10db3554ba03a81166c27aa94ba27c335769 7cdd834509731c8946d6fde > /dev/null 2>&1) returned 256`

As whenever I'm not running an additional script `/home/BTC/block.js` is automatically deleted.

Why does bitcoin debug ignore `/dev/null 2>&1` and how do I stop it?

**@m1xolyd1an, sorry if I am not clear:**

The %s gives the block hash to the block.js nodejs script if the script exists (and when it does block.js accepts the hash fine and does what it needs to do). The problem is that the instruction to ignore all errors in the conf is not upheld by bitcoind, thus, my debug.log looks terrible when blocks.js does not exist. blocks.js only exists when it is created by another script and when that script terminates it deletes blocks.js

Comment: What are you trying to do with the %s data all by itself after block.js? I think your space after .js and before %s might be causing the problem. If you want to pass the data as a GET do something like `/home/BTC/block.js?q=%s`

Comment: No it works fine with no error when the file exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log message

```
runCommand error: system(/root/.nvm/versions/node/v11.15.0/bin/node /home/BTC/block.js ea31b10db3554ba03a81166c27aa94ba27c335769 7cdd834509731c8946d6fde > /dev/null 2>&1) returned 256
```

is not an error log entry produced by `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v11.15.0/bin/node` (as such output would be redirected to /dev/null). It is an error reported by `bitcoind` because the command invoked returned failure. Redirecting output does not change the return value of a command.

Try adding `|| true` at the end of the command.